# How to extend this arrow and change position of label

Tags: arrows, labels, tikz-cd

I have the following diagram which used the following code

```
\begin{tikzcd}
\phi\times\psi\times\theta \arrow[r,"_{X_{p}}{\circ}_{Y_q}\times \Id"]
\arrow[d,"\cong"]
&
(\phi _{X_p}\circ _{Y_q}\psi)\times \theta\arrow[d]
\\
\phi\times \theta \times \psi \arrow[d,"_{X_r}\circ_{Z_t}\times \Id"']
&
\arrow[d,phantom]
\\
(\phi _{X_r}\circ_{Z_t})\times \psi\arrow[r,"(\phi_{X_r}\circ_{Z_t}\theta)_{X_p}\circ_{Y_q}\psi"]
&
(\phi_{X_p}\circ_{Y_q}\psi)_{X_r}\circ_{Z_t}\theta
\end{tikzcd}
```

In this diagram you can see one of the arrows does not go all the way down to the lower right corner (which is where I want it to go). One can also see that the label at the bottom of the diagram is too close to the arrow. I would like to move it a bit further down.

It seems I must have something at the (2,2) node, otherwise Latex will not even compile the diagram. Hence I have put the phantom arrow. A picture of my commutative diagram is below.

[image: Picture of my diagram]

Comment: Please do add your packages you have used in your document starting from `\documentclass[•]{•}`(i.e MWE) which will defines your problem@Damo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applied `column sep = 80` and `row sep = 30` without `\hspace`:

```
    \documentclass[]{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz-cd}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd} [column sep = 80, row sep = 30]
       \phi\times\psi\times\theta \arrow[d,"\cong"] \arrow[r,"{X_p}{\circ}_{Y_q}\times Id"] &
       (\phi _{X_p}\circ _{Y_q}\psi)\times \theta\arrow[dd] \\ 
       \phi\times\psi\times\psi \arrow[d,"X_r{\circ}_{Z_t}\times Id"']  &  \\
       (\phi _{X_r}\circ_{Z_t})\times \psi \ar[r,"(\phi_{X_r}\circ_{Z_t}\theta)_{X_p}\circ_{Y_q}\psi"]
     & (\phi_{X_p}\circ_{Y_q}\psi)_{X_r}\circ_{Z_t}\theta
    \end{tikzcd}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would not expect that my answer will be accepted. I just wanted to show what @Arzigoglu suggested. What should I do? I feel like a thief now :(.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `\arrow[dd]` (no need for `\arrow[d,phantom]`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator\Id{Id}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
\phi\times\psi\times\theta \arrow[r,"_{X_{p}}{\circ}_{Y_q}\times \Id"] \arrow[d,"\cong"]          & (\phi _{X_p}\circ _{Y_q}\psi)\times \theta\arrow[dd] \\
\phi\times \theta \times \psi \arrow[d,"_{X_r}\circ_{Z_t}\times \Id"']                            &                                                      \\
(\phi _{X_r}\circ_{Z_t})\times \psi\arrow[r,"(\phi_{X_r}\circ_{Z_t}\theta)_{X_p}\circ_{Y_q}\psi"] & (\phi_{X_p}\circ_{Y_q}\psi)_{X_r}\circ_{Z_t}\theta   \\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would add `[column sep=70]` to the `tikzcd` options for a better looking diagram

Answer (score 2):

`\arrow[dd]` command taken from Henri Menke answer and I have used`shorten` to change the length of an arrow and `\hspace*{}` to change the horizontal position of text so as  to make looks figure better.

```
  \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
  \usepackage{tikz-cd}
  \begin{document}
  \begin{tikzcd}
  \phi\times\psi\times\theta \arrow[d,"\cong"] \arrow[r,"{X_p}{\circ}_{Y_q}\times Id"] &  (\phi _{X_p}\circ _{Y_q}\psi)\times \theta\arrow[dd] \\ 
 \phi\times\psi\times\psi \arrow[d,"X_r{\circ}_{Z_t}\times Id"']  &  \\
  (\phi _{X_r}\circ_{Z_t})\times \psi \ar[r,shorten >=- 1.7cm,"\hspace*{1.4cm}(\phi_{X_r}\circ_{Z_t}\theta)_{X_p}\circ_{Y_q}\psi"]
  & \hspace*{1.7cm}(\phi_{X_p}\circ_{Y_q}\psi)_{X_r}\circ_{Z_t}\theta
 \end{tikzcd}

  \end{document}
```

[image]